# How does an instance of pytorch's `nn.Linear()` process a tuple of tensors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, transformer-model

In the [annotated transformer's implementation of multi-head attention](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/annotated-transformer/), three tensors (query, key, value) are all passed to a `nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)`:

```
# some class definition ...
self.linears = clones(nn.Linear(d_model, d_model), 4) # deep-copied list of nn.Linear-modules concatenated via nn.ModuleList
# more code ...
query, key, value = [
  lin(x).view(nbatches, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
  for lin, x in zip(self.linears, (query, key, value))
]
```

My question: what happens at `lin(x)`, when an instance of `nn.Linear()` is called on the tuple `(query, key, value)`? Is the tuple somehow concatenated to a tensor? If so, how - on which dimension are the tensors concatenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
self.linears = clones(nn.Linear(d_model, d_model), 4) # deep-copied list of nn.Linear-modules concatenated via nn.ModuleList
# more code ...
query, key, value = [
  lin(x).view(nbatches, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
  for lin, x in zip(self.linears, (query, key, value))
]
```

Actually, the `nn.Linear` does not process input as a tuple of a `Q,K,V`.
In your code, the result similar like this

```py
out_Q = self.linears[0](Q)
out_K = self.linears[1](K)
out_V = self.linears[2](V)
```

When you use zip(iterable A, iterable B)
So you will get the pairs (A[0], B[0]) (A[1], B[1]) ,... **independently**

Or more specific

```py
query = self.linears[0](query)
key = self.linears[1](key)
value = self.linears[2](value)
```

Comment: Thanks - so my question was not pytorch-related at all.